# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] true in

Tags: php, web-services, soap

i m using php soapclent, other calls are working good with this URL.here is the snap of the request to be passed.

[image]

not getting what is the problem ?

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client]
>   true in C:\wamp\www\ginger\createEditProfile.php:8 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www\ginger\createEditProfile.php(8):
>   SoapClient->__soapCall('createEditProfi...', Array) #1 {main} thrown
>   in C:\wamp\www\ginger\createEditProfile.php on line 8

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$sc = new SoapClient("http://###.###.##.##/GingerIBE/services/consolidatedServicesBean.wsdl?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));

$params =array('targetProfile'=>array('loginId'=>'bhav1234','password'=>'test123','preferredHotel'=>'', 'customerId'=>'','firstName'=>'Bhavina','lastName'=>'Prajapati','customerType'=>'1','customerAccountGroup'=>'SH01','gender'=>'Female','dateOfBirth'=>'1987-11-01','emailId'=>'testing.abc@gmail.com','mobileNumber'=>'8866853905','phoneNumber'=>'8866853906','faxNumber'=>'8866853901','preferredModeOfContact'=>'','addressLine1'=>'some address line 1','addressLine2'=>'some address line 2','pinNumber'=>'','city'=>'Bangalore','state'=>'Karnataka','country'=>'India'));

$result = $sc->__soapCall('createEditProfile', array('parameters' => $params));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo($sc->__getLastRequest());
```

Comment: if you catch the exception what does it say?

Comment: its just giving true as o/p of  `$e->getMessage()`

Comment: i have a doubt -to passing targetProfile[] as we seen in the snap -in another way.

Comment: trurn trace on and see what the last response was http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php